# What is the difference between GA and stable version?

Tags: cassandra

What is the difference between Apache Cassandra Stable version and General availability version.
Is that mean General availability version may have more bugs than stable version ? Or it is something else. Kindly clarify what are the criterias for this segregation

https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All generally available (GA) versions are stable but not all stable versions are GA. Allow me to explain further.

At the time of writing (Feb 2024), the GA (stable) versions are:

- Cassandra 4.1
- Cassandra 4.0
- Cassandra 3.11
- Cassandra 3.0

Older versions of Cassandra such as 2.2 and 2.1 are also stable versions but they have reached end-of-life (EOL) so are no longer GA.

Cassandra 4.1 is the "latest" GA version, so is 4.0 except that it's not the latest -- that's the only distinction.

For more info, see [Apache Cassandra Release Lifecycle](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/tQzjBw). Cheers!

Comment: Many Thanks Erick